# Syntactically how these two statements return the same value in python?

Tags: python

Syntactically how these two statements return the same value?

```
x ,= range(1)
print(x) # prints 0

(x,) = range(1)
print(x) # here also prints 0
```

Comment: x, and (x, ) how internally it is treating?

Comment: It's the comma that makes a tuple, the parentheses are optional in most circumstances.

Comment: The parentheses symbols are optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 operations at work:

1. Tuple construction
2. Sequence unpacking

As mentioned, the comma makes a variable a `tuple`. This is true in both instances.

In addition, these are examples of *sequence unpacking*. In other words, the element(s) of `range(1)` are unpacked and attributed to the element(s) of the `tuple`, in this case `(x, )`.

Since these are tuples of length 1, the single element unpacked from `range(1)`, i.e. 0, is assigned to `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Check this for example:

```
v1 = 1,
v2 = (1,)

type(v1)  # outputs <type 'tuple'>
type(v2)  # outputs <type 'tuple'>
```

Comma makes a tuple from the expression while the parentheses are just optional.

Answer (score 0):

Both are tuples , () optinally

```
In [29]: a=x,

In [30]: b=(x,)

In [32]: type(a)
Out[32]: tuple

In [33]: type(b)
Out[33]: tuple

In [34]:
```

lets says if u put y after comma and make range(2)
then it unpacks the both value and assign to x and y respectively

```
In [36]: x,y=range(2)

In [37]: x,y
Out[37]: (0, 1)

In [38]: (x,y)=range(2)

In [39]: x,y
Out[39]: (0, 1)
```